# Translating inittab line to Ubuntu 9.04 jaunty system equivalent

Tags: services, init

I'm trying to use `runit` on my SheevaPlug running Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty. There is a helpful tutorial at TechRepublic ([Use runit to supervise Linux services](http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/opensource/?p=202)) that walks through the process of setting it up, but it says:

> edit /etc/inittab and add:
>
> SV:123456:respawn:/sbin/runsvdir-start
>
> to the bottom of the file. This will
>   start (and re-start, if it ever exits)
>   the /sbin/runsvdir-start program.

I found a post saying that [inittab isn't used in some ubuntu versions](http://blog.mypapit.net/2007/03/where-can-i-find-inittab-in-ubuntu-edgy-eft-or-feisty-fawn.html). I can install/use `chkconfig` or `update-rc.d`, but I don't really know what I'm doing or how to translate the above statement into arguments for either tool. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Jaunty is no longer supported (it reached [End-Of-Life](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2010-September/001166.html) last month), so I would recommend upgrading (go to 10.04 if you need a long-lived system). However, when you upgrade to a version that uses [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), you can create a file in the `/etc/init` directory to do what you need. For example, create `/etc/init/sheevaplug.conf`:

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[123456]
stop on runlevel [!123456]

respawn
exec /sbin/runsvdir-start
```

That is a direct translation of the `inittab` line you gave, and should behave similarly with Upstart. You can start and stop it with `service sheevaplug start` and `service sheevaplug stop`, etc.

Comment: Is there actually any point in using `runit`, as `upstart` already supports supervising?  (Maybe runit does it better, I've never used it.)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know much about `runit`. If there is a better path to use on the `exec` line, go for it. Upstart will track its lifetime.

Comment: So it turns out that upstart has been in Ubuntu since 6.10, so it's already installed on my system. However, I don't have an `/etc/init` directory. Can I just create the folder (and the script inside it) and upstart will detect and run it? Since I don't have to use `runit`, I'll just modify the script to call my executable directly.

Comment: Apparently, `runit` has the ability to redirect output from a script to a logger service (http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/opensource/?p=207&tag=rbxccnbtr1). Do you know if upstart provides a similar mechanism?